# building '_mysql' extension error: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified

Tags: python, django, pycharm

I have been trying to install mysqlclient to communicate with python but i always get this error below. I have tried installing from command prompt too but it says "module setup tools is not found"
can someone tell show me what's wrong? Thanks

I have been trying to install mysqlclient to communicate with python but i always get this error below. I have tried installing from command prompt too but it says "module setup tools is not found"
can someone tell show me what's wrong? Thanks

```
(venv) C:\Users\kesh\PycharmProjects\SplashSongs>pip3 install mysqlclient
Collecting mysqlclient
Using cached 

https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/ec
/fd/83329b9d3e14f7344d1cb31f128e6dbba70c5975c9e57896815dbb1988ad/
mysqlclient-1.3.13.tar.gz

Installing collected packages: mysqlclient
Running setup.py install for mysqlclient ... error

Complete output from command
C:\Users\kesh\PycharmProjects\SplashSongs\venv\Scripts\python.exe -u
-c "import setuptools, 
tokenize;__file__='C:\\Users\\kesh\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\

pip-install-3qsuf31w\\mysqlclient\\setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize,
'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n',
'\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install -
-record C:\Users\kesh\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-6eq7cdv9\install-record.txt
--single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers \ Users\kesh\PycharmProjects\SplashSongs\venv\include\site\python3.5\mysqlclient:C:\Users\kesh\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\distutils\dist.py:261:
 UserWarning: Unknown distribution option:
'long_description_content_type' warnings.warn(msg)

running install
running build
running build_py
creating build
creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.5
copying _mysql_exceptions.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.5
creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\MySQLdb
copying MySQLdb\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\MySQLdb
copying MySQLdb\compat.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\MySQLdb
copying MySQLdb\connections.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\MySQLdb
copying MySQLdb\converters.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\MySQLdb
copying MySQLdb\cursors.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\MySQLdb
copying MySQLdb\release.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\MySQLdb
copying MySQLdb\times.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\MySQLdb
creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\MySQLdb\constants
copying MySQLdb\constants\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\MySQLdb\constants
copying MySQLdb\constants\CLIENT.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\MySQLdb\constants
copying MySQLdb\constants\CR.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\MySQLdb\constants
copying MySQLdb\constants\ER.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\MySQLdb\constants
copying MySQLdb\constants\FIELD_TYPE.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\MySQLdb\constants
copying MySQLdb\constants\FLAG.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\MySQLdb\constants
copying MySQLdb\constants\REFRESH.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\MySQLdb\constants
running build_ext
building '_mysql' extension
error: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified

----------------------------------------
Command "C:\Users\kesh\PycharmProjects\SplashSongs\venv\Scripts\python.exe -u 
-c "import setuptools, 
tokenize;__file__='C:\\Users\\kesh\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install- 
3qsuf31w\\msqlclient\\setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open) 
(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, 
__file__, 'exec'))" install --record C:\Users\kesh\ApData\Local\Temp\pip- 
record-6eq7cdv9\install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed -- 
compile --install-headers 
C:\Users\kesh\PycharmProjects\SplashSongs\venv\include\site\python3.5\my
sqlclient" failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\kesh\AppData\Local\Temp\pip- 
install-3qsuf31w\mysqlclient\

(venv) C:\Users\kesh\PycharmProjects\SplashSongs>pip3 install mysqlclient
Collecting mysqlclient
Using cached 

https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/ec
/fd/83329b9d3e14f7344d1cb31f128e6dbba70c5975c9e57896815dbb1988ad/
mysqlclient-1.3.13.tar.gz

Installing collected packages: mysqlclient
Running setup.py install for mysqlclient ... error

Complete output from command
C:\Users\kesh\PycharmProjects\SplashSongs\venv\Scripts\python.exe -u
-c "import setuptools, 
tokenize;__file__='C:\\Users\\kesh\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\

pip-install-3qsuf31w\\mysqlclient\\setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize,
'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n',
'\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install -
-record C:\Users\kesh\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-6eq7cdv9\install-record.txt
--single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers \ Users\kesh\PycharmProjects\SplashSongs\venv\include\site\python3.5\mysqlclient:C:\Users\kesh\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\distutils\dist.py:261:
 UserWarning: Unknown distribution option:
'long_description_content_type' warnings.warn(msg)

running install
running build
running build_py
creating build
creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.5
copying _mysql_exceptions.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.5
creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\MySQLdb
copying MySQLdb\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\MySQLdb
copying MySQLdb\compat.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\MySQLdb
copying MySQLdb\connections.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\MySQLdb
copying MySQLdb\converters.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\MySQLdb
copying MySQLdb\cursors.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\MySQLdb
copying MySQLdb\release.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\MySQLdb
copying MySQLdb\times.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\MySQLdb
creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\MySQLdb\constants
copying MySQLdb\constants\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\MySQLdb\constants
copying MySQLdb\constants\CLIENT.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\MySQLdb\constants
copying MySQLdb\constants\CR.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\MySQLdb\constants
copying MySQLdb\constants\ER.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\MySQLdb\constants
copying MySQLdb\constants\FIELD_TYPE.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\MySQLdb\constants
copying MySQLdb\constants\FLAG.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\MySQLdb\constants
copying MySQLdb\constants\REFRESH.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\MySQLdb\constants
running build_ext
building '_mysql' extension
error: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified

----------------------------------------
Command "C:\Users\kesh\PycharmProjects\SplashSongs\venv\Scripts\python.exe -u 
-c "import setuptools, 
tokenize;__file__='C:\\Users\\kesh\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install- 
3qsuf31w\\msqlclient\\setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open) 
(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, 
__file__, 'exec'))" install --record C:\Users\kesh\ApData\Local\Temp\pip- 
record-6eq7cdv9\install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed -- 
compile --install-headers 
C:\Users\kesh\PycharmProjects\SplashSongs\venv\include\site\python3.5\my
sqlclient" failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\kesh\AppData\Local\Temp\pip- 
install-3qsuf31w\mysqlclient\
```

Comment: Could you tell us what system you're on and what you've tried already to fix the problem? And could you format the commands a bit to make it easier for others to read? https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code. That'll help make it easier for people to understand your question.

Comment: I am on windows 7, i have tried installing with command prompt, it isn't working

Answer (score 2):

Go to https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#mysqlclient and download a precompiled mysqlclient library for your python version. For an example if you are using python 3.6 32bit version, download

> mysqlclient‑1.3.13‑cp36‑cp36m‑win32.whl

Then from either command prompt or pycharm terminal(pycharm terminal if you want to install for the virtual environment of your project) execute

```
pip install "Path for the downloaded .whl file"
```

That should install mysqlclient without a problem.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, i've tried that, this is yet its result:

    (venv) C:\Users\kesh\PycharmProjects\SplashSongs>pip install 
    C:\Users\kesh\Downloads\mysqlclient-1.3.13-cp36-cp36m-win32.whl

     mysqlclient-1.3.13-cp36-cp36m-win32.whl is not a supported wheel on this 
     platform.

Comment: If you are having python 3.5, try cp35 cp35 whl file